# Android Emulator not connecting to internet (hyper-v device manager, win10, Xamarin development)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator

My android emulator is not connecting to the internet. I discovered this when debugging my mobile application and seeing it crash when trying to connect to my web service.

I then opened the devices by themselves and tried to open a web page in the browser and the device is not connected.

This happens for my android device and my windows device.

windows device
`Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB.jwierzba`

android device
`VS Emulator 5-inch KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone.jwierzba`

I have not modified the network adapter settings. How can I find out why the device is not using my local pcs internet connection? (LAN and wireless)

running Windows 10 Pro x64

Comment: Are you running this on a VM by any chance?

Comment: @nitinsh99 No I am running the emulator on windows 10 through visual studio 2015 when I deploy and debug my xamarin.android application

Comment: check your emulator VM in Hyper-V Manager. You might have some VirtualBox ones. Make sure your Internal Network Adapter is set to Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch and External Adapter is set to your real PC adapter. Remove the rest if any exist

Comment: @YuriS I have those two set up internal and external, but there are indeed two additional external adapters I will try removing that

Comment: I assume it works now?